Bases of $T_Z \mathbb R^2 \otimes \mathbb C$
Let $z= x+ iy$, I know the bases of $T_z \mathbb R^2$ is $(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}, \frac{\partial }{\partial y})$.
From this problem, I treat $T_z\mathbb R^2 \otimes \mathbb C$ as
$\{  z_1\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + z_2 \frac{\partial }{\partial y} : z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb C  \}$.  Therefore, the bases of $T_z\mathbb R^2 \otimes \mathbb C$  still be $(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}, \frac{\partial }{\partial y})$.
Now, from the red line of picture below, I have
$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}=\frac{\partial }{\partial z} + \frac{\partial }{\partial \overline z}$
and
$
\frac{\partial }{\partial y}= i(\frac{\partial }{\partial z}-\frac{\partial }{\partial \overline z} )
$.
Namely,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\\
 \frac{\partial }{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
i & -i
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial }{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial }{\partial \overline z}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since $\det\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
i & -i
\end{pmatrix} \ne 0$, $(\frac{\partial }{\partial z}, \frac{\partial }{\partial \overline z})$ also be bases of  $T_z\mathbb R^2 \otimes \mathbb C$.
Am I right about these ideas?



